# Add two UIView to UIScrollView like HORIZONTAL ViewPager in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

How can I set two UIView like items of UIScrollView. I've code which must be do that but its't work for me!
Any idea please! Thanks!

```
let scrollView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: containerView.frame)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: containerView.frame.width * CGFloat(2), height: containerView.frame.height)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .black
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        
        containerView.addSubview(scrollView)
        

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [
                scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
                scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
                scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
                scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
            ]
        )
        
        
        
        let innerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: containerView.frame.width * CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: scrollView.frame.width, height: containerView.frame.height))
        innerView.backgroundColor = .brown
        scrollView.addSubview(innerView)

        
        
        let innerView1:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: containerView.frame.width * CGFloat(1), y: CGFloat(0), width: containerView.frame.width, height: containerView.frame.height))
        innerView1.backgroundColor = .red
        scrollView.addSubview(innerView1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly set scrollview's `contentSize` to some value. Assuming you've already setup your scrollview's constraints, you can do the following:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    // This constraint tells the scroll view that innerView is constrained to the 'beginning' of the scroll
    innerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            
    // If you want to set the explicit width of the innerView
    // Add the following constraint:
    innerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            
    // Or you may want it's width to be equal to scrollview's width
    // If so, add this constraint:
    innerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
            
    innerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor),
    innerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
    innerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
    innerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
            
    // This constraint tells the scroll view that innerView1 is constrained to the 'end' of the innerView
    innerView1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.trailingAnchor),
            
    innerView1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor),
    innerView1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
    innerView1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
    innerView1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),
            
    // This constraint tells the scroll view that innerView1's 'end' is equal to scrollview's end
    innerView1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
])
```

There are two ways of getting paging working. The first one is by setting `isPadingEnabled` which in most cases does not work properly. The second one is by implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol method:

```swift
var currentPage: Int = 0

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
     // Stop the scroll view from scrolling any further
     targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
     
     if velocity.x > 0 {
          // we're scrolling to the previous page
          currentPage -= 1
     } else if velocity.x < 0 {
          // we're scrolling to the next page
          currentPage += 1
     } else {
          // you might also have to handle the case when the gesture velocity is 0
     }
     
     let desiredOffset = CGPoint(x: currentPage * pageWidth, y: 0)
     scrollView.setContentOffset(desiredOffset, animated: true)
}
```

You could also experiment with it a bit and wrap `scrollView.setContentOffset` in a `UIView.animate` block with `animated` parameter set to `false`.

Answer (score -1):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
if scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0 {
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
}
```

}

you must set the scrollView delegate like that and then executed the above method：

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

I don't know your demand, if your time is enough, you can write it by yourself as a library, but you also can use

> XLPagerTabStrip

.